How do I know what version of Ubuntu I have if I can't log in or get to tty?
I have a problem where I can't log into the system.
It freezes when I enter the right details.
I can't get to a tty or terminal either.
When I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 a blank screen shows up, and if I press any key it returns me to the log in screen.
Ctrl+Alt+Fx (where x is any number) also doesn't work.
Alt and T during bootup let me stay in the bootup code but again when I type anything it sends me to the login screen.
I thought I installed Ubuntu 23.04 when I first (recently) installed it. But how do I check this?
I realise it might have updated (I was running updates before it stopped working) so it could be 24.04. Which would make sense cause when I tried to install 24.04 it didn't work.

sometimes grub/bootloader will show the version of the installed OS in the text entries, but this is likely the old version you installed, not the one which is running now if it was upgraded

I'm doing this rather often actually (most installs are QA installs so often not used post-install) and as there maybe multiple OSes on the system I don't want to boot & look at each one at a time.  I boot live and its usually pretty easy. The answer by @kos isn't usually what I do, but there are many clues, but most are unique to specific OSes, eg. kernel details in /boot/ narrow it down well (inc. OS), /var/log/installer contains details of install for Ubuntu systems; /var/log/dist-upgrade will give release-upgrade clues;  file-system metadata tells gives clues as to when etc.

Systemd-based distros (though this doesn't apply only to systemd-based distros) store much information about the current release in /etc/os-release (which is one of the files parsed by lsb_release), optionally including (Ubuntu does), among others, for example, a VERSION_ID entry:

A lower-case string (mostly numeric, no spaces or other characters outside of 0–9, a–z, ".", "_" and "-") identifying the operating system version, excluding any OS name information or release code name, and suitable for processing by scripts or usage in generated filenames. This field is optional.

and a PRETTY_NAME entry:

A pretty operating system name in a format suitable for presentation to the user. May or may not contain a release code name or OS version of some kind, as suitable. If not set, a default of "PRETTY_NAME="Linux"" may be used

% grep '^VERSION_ID=' /etc/os-release
VERSION_ID="24.04"
% grep '^PRETTY_NAME=' /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"

So you may:

Boot from a Live ISO
Mount the system disk's root partition somewhere (e.g. sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt, replacing /dev/sdXY with the right block device for your root partition as listed by, say, lsblk)
Run
grep '^VERSION_ID=' /mnt/etc/os-release

to print the VERSION_ID entry, or
grep '^PRETTY_NAME=' /mnt/etc/os-release

to print the PRETTY_NAME entry

Note that on Ubuntu 24.04.1 at least the PRETTY_NAME entry contains the specific point release version ("24.04.1", unlike VERSION_ID, which just contains "24.04"), so that's another reason to prefer PRETTY_NAME over VERSION_ID when not parsing the file to script stuff.
